# Does spellstrike override spell storing for a Magus?

Tags: pathfinder-1e, magic-items, touch-attacks, magus, pathfinder-society

After getting keen I am exploring other options for my *Pathfinder Society* level 8 Magus. This is my first caster character of any sort, so forgive me if I'm forgetting something obvious.

Consider the following scenario:

- Cast shocking grasp into my scimitar with *spell storing* enchant
- Next round reveals electricity immune baddie
- Attack baddie with scimitar, choosing not to unleash held spell
- Next round cast *frigid touch* and deliver with spellstrike

My question in this scenario is: If you deliver a held spell with spellstrike through a weapon with *spell storing*, does it "clear" out the stored spell (much like what happens if you cast a spell while still holding one as a caster).

Answer (score 8, accepted):

No. You have to explicitly cast the spell into a *spell storing* weapon in order to store the spell.

> (much like what happens if you cast a spell while still holding one as a caster)

Simply holding the weapon while you cast a spell does not automatically fill an empty *spell storing* weapon, not even for normal casters.

You can choose not to activate the stored spell, and cast *frigid touch* through [*spellstrike*](http://www.d20pfsrd.com/classes/base-classes/magus#TOC-Spellstrike-Su-). Your *shocking grasp* remains stored until you discharge it or explicitly store another spell in your weapon. Further note, although you didn't ask - the stored *shocking grasp* does not get the enhanced critical range from *spellstrike*, because it's discharged from the item, not using your ability.

I'm not able to find any specific FAQs. To parse RAW:

> Once the spell has been cast from the weapon, a spellcaster can cast any other targeted spell of up to 3rd level into it.

They cast the spell into the weapon instead of the standard target. Targeting always requires specific intent. Without this intent, you're not actually doing anything with the spell storing property. Spellstrike is a separate ability which acts independently of spell storing.

Answer (score -1):

Compare, if you will, the weapon here to a conducting wire with rubber sleeve. The sleeve is your stored spell, wrapped tightly around the wire, your weapon. The rubber insulation doesn't change just because you apply and electric current (your spell delivered by spellstrike). The same applies to your stored spell. Admittedly, the analogy can only go so far. Hope it helped, though.
 So, to reiterate: when you use spellstrike, the weapon serves as a conductor, albeit a sharp edged one which does its own damage on contact.your stored spell is inert until you activate it, hence the comparison with the insulation around the wire.

Comment: Can you give any reasons why we *should* think of weapons in this manner? I do not see anything in the game’s text that suggests that this is an apt comparison.

Comment: @Raetjor Hey, be nice ([it's a rule here](http://rpg.stackexchange.com/help/be-nice)). We can have disagreements about content without making it personal. Feedback is a normal part of our community process here. It's usually intended to reveal points of possible improvement in a post, though of course you're free to ignore, civilly rebut, or use it—as you judge appropriate and useful.

Comment: @SevenSidedDie, I am all for being friendly, but not if I am made target of another user's onslaught of complaints about every single post simply because he is fixated on finding a flaw.

Comment: FWIW, most of what comments are for is addressing what may improve a reply to a question.  While that may come across as a barrage of criticism, that is the general purpose of a comment: address something in a reply in hopes that it will improve it, or to clarify a point.  It is in the community's interest to help improve answers.  Per the text at the [tour] "Use comments to ask for more information or clarify a question or answer."

Comment: Korvin speaks truth. Also note that the same user being the source of the comments is not a sign of personal targetting: the user in question is the highest-rep Pathfinder user here, so it's not surprising that they looked at your posts and had feedback to offer.

Comment: Insofar as your answer goes, your analogy might be better in terms of a capacitor.  If the capacitor is already charged, then it has to release a charge before it can store up another one.  If you'd like to use that analogy, rather than the one you offered, feel free to do so.  (Shipping and handling is free as well. :-) )